# insert or update on table "customers" violates foreign key constraint "fk_carts_owner"

Tags: sql, go

I have following set of models.

```
type Customer struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID                int       `gorm:"primaryKey;unique;"`
    Username          string    `gorm:"<-:create;unique;type:varchar(100);null:false;" json:"username"`
    Password          string    `gorm:"type:varchar(100);null:false;" json:"password"`
    Email             string    `gorm:"<-:create;unique;type:varchar(100);null:false;" json:"email"`
    CreatedAt         string    `gorm:"<-:create;type:date;uniqueIndex;" sql:"type:timestamp without time zone" json:"createdAt"`
    PurchasedProducts []Product `gorm:"many2many:purchased_products;default:null;"`
}



type Cart struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID        int       `gorm:"primaryKey;unique;"`
    OwnerId   int       `gorm:"<-:create;unique;type:int;NOT NILL;" json:"OwnerId"`
    Owner     Customer  `gorm:"foreignKey:ID;references:OwnerId;OnDelete:cascade;default:null;"`
    Products  []Product `gorm:"many2many:products;default:null;"`
    CreatedAt string    `gorm:"->;uniqueIndex;type:date;"`
}
```

SQL Version of them

```
CREATE TABLE customers(
   id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   Username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   Password VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
   Email    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE cart(
  id BIGSERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  OwnerId INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Owner FOREIGN KEY (OwnerId) REFERENCES customer(id)
)
```

So the problem is when I Create new `Customer`,
the `Cart` Model triggers an exception `ERROR: insert or update on table "customers" violates foreign key constraint "fk_carts_owner" (SQLSTATE 23503)`,

Can you please correct the models if there is something wrong with their relations..

What I want is `One Customer can have one Cart` (basically foreign key)

So I find a bit different the concept of foreign keys in Golang ORM's, rather then Python, so getting used to it.

Comment: no you don't need a foreign key ,you need a priamry key on (Id,ownerId) the foreign neeeds to have the customer added before you add a new cart

Comment: can you please provide an example)?

Comment: + I create customer before creating any carts, but it throws an exception anyway

Comment: which one exactly?

Comment: ERROR: insert or update on table "customers" violates foreign key constraint "fk_carts_owner" (SQLSTATE 23503)

Comment: that means that you tried to update the owner id, that was already in the card, the concept of our seems a bit off, so you need to evaluate your strategy